# In Linux copy file and overwrite only if target is older

Tags: linux, cp

How in Linux using `cp` one can copy file to destination, but if destination exists, then overwrite only if destination is older than source?

`cp -f` always overwrites, but overwrite is needed only if target is older than source.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
cp -u
```

According to the [cp man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?cp), -u will only overwrite file if the destination is older than the source.

It appears the -u option is not available for scp, so if you need to do it on a remote host, use [rsync](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync). By default, rsync skips files that have the same size, name, and last modified time. Rsync also has a -u option to skip destination files that are newer.